# Custom sentence boundary detection in SpaCy

Tags: python, nlp, spacy

I'm trying to write a custom sentence segmenter in spaCy that returns the whole document as a single sentence.

I wrote a custom pipeline component that does it using the code from [here](https://github.com/explosion/spaCy/issues/1850).

I can't get it to work though, because instead of changing the sentence boundaries to take the whole document as a single sentence it throws two different errors.

If I create a blank language instance and only add my custom component to the pipeline I get this error:

```
ValueError: Sentence boundary detection requires the dependency parse, which requires a statistical model to be installed and loaded.
```

If I add the parser component to the pipeline

```
nlp = spacy.blank('es')
parser = nlp.create_pipe('parser')
nlp.add_pipe(parser, last=True)
def custom_sbd(doc):
    print("EXECUTING SBD!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!")
    doc[0].sent_start = True
    for i in range(1, len(doc)):
        doc[i].sent_start = False
    return doc
nlp.begin_training()
nlp.add_pipe(custom_sbd, first=True)
```

I get the same error.

If I change the order for it to parse first and then change the sentence boundaries, the error changes to

```
Refusing to write to token.sent_start if its document is parsed, because this may cause inconsistent state.
```

So if it throws an error requiring the dependency parse if it's not present or it executes after the custom sentence boundary detection, and a different error when the dependency parse is executed first, what's the appropriate way to do it?

Thank you!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Ines from spaCy answered my question [here](https://github.com/explosion/spaCy/issues/1885)

> Thanks for bringing this up – and sorry this is a little confusing.
>   I'm pretty sure the first problem you describe is already fixed on
>   master. spaCy should definitely respect custom sentence boundaries,
>   even in pipelines with no dependency parser.
>
> If you want to use your custom SBD component without a parser, a very
>   simple solution would be to set doc.is_parsed = True in your custom
>   component. So when Doc.sents checks for the dependency parse, it looks
>   at is_parsed and won't complain.
>
> If you want to use your component with the parser, make sure to add it
>   before the parser. The parser should always respect already set
>   sentence boundaries from previous processing steps.