# SpaCy save model to disk with custom Sentencizer error

Tags: python, oop, nlp, spacy

I know similar questions were asked:

[Spacy custom sentence spliting](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54529875/spacy-custom-sentence-spliting)

[Custom sentence boundary detection in SpaCy](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48443624/custom-sentence-boundary-detection-in-spacy)

yet my situation is a little different.
I want to inherit from the spacy Sentencizer() with:

```py
from spacy.pipeline import Sentencizer

class MySentencizer(Sentencizer):
    def __init__(self):
        self.tok = create_mySentencizer() # returning the sentences

    def __call__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        doc = args[0]
        for tok in doc:
            # do set the boundaries with tok.is_sent_start 
        return doc
```

Even tho splitting works fine if I call
`doc = nlp("Text and so on. Another sentence.")`
after updating the model:

```py
  nlp = spacy.load("some_model")
  sentencizer = MySentencizer()
  nlp.add_pipe(sentencizer, before="parser")
  # update model
```

when i want to save the trained model with:

`nlp.to_disk("path/to/my/model")`

I get the following error:

`AttributeError: 'MySentencizer' object has no attribute 'punct_chars'`

Contrary, if i use the nlp.add_pipe(nlp.create_pipe('sentencizer')) the error does not occur.
I wonder at what point I should have set the punct_chars attribute. It should have been inherited from the superclass?

If i replace the Sentencizer from the class and do object according to the first post,
it works, but I may lose some valuable information on the way e.g. punct_chars?

Thanks for help in advance.

Chris

Comment: Be aware that you probably don't want to extend the `Sentencizer` like this. As it is, `nlp()` will call your custom method `__call__` but `nlp.pipe()` will call the `Sentencizer.pipe`, which will apply a completely different sentence segmentation. Instead, if you're concerned about serialization, you can implement dummy `to/from_bytes/disk` methods in your custom component that don't do anything. Alternatively, you can also implement `pipe` in your subclass, but if you're not using the sentencizer punctuation or methods, it'd be cleaner for your class to be separate.

Comment: Thanks @aab for your comment. I am aware on this problems now. Can you give me an example of how an implementation of a dummy to/from_bytes/disk method in my component looks like, that does not do anything? Or more intersting, how to wirte a pip subclass for my case?

Comment: Look at the `DummyTokenizer` in `spacy.util` as an example.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following should do (note `super(MySentencizer, self).__init__()`):

```
import spacy
from spacy.pipeline import Sentencizer

class MySentencizer(Sentencizer):
    def __init__(self):
        super(MySentencizer, self).__init__() 

    def __call__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        doc = args[0]
        for tok in doc:
            tok.is_sent_start = True if tok.orth == "." else False
        return doc

nlp = spacy.load("en_core_web_md")
sentencizer = MySentencizer()
nlp.add_pipe(sentencizer, before="parser")

nlp.to_disk("model")
```